# apache bench keep alive got 0 document length

Tags: http, curl, keep-alive, apachebench

I used bellow command:
ab -k -n 1 -c 1 -v 5 $URL
and got:

```
LOG: header received:
Blockquote

HTTP/1.1 200 OK

content-length: 228

content-type: application/octet-stream
date: Fri, 26 Feb 2016 03:09:27 GMT
expires: Fri, 26 Feb 2016 03:10:27 GMT
cache-control: private, max-age=60
last-modified: Thu, 18 Feb 2016 07:02:46 GMT
connection: keep-alive`


LOG: Response code = 200
..done

...

Document Length:        0 bytes

Concurrency Level:      1
Time taken for tests:   0.019 seconds
Complete requests:      1
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Keep-Alive requests:    1
Total transferred:      263 bytes
HTML transferred:       0 bytes
Requests per second:    52.44 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       19.068 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       19.068 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          13.47 [Kbytes/sec] received
```

ab received the header: `content-length: 228`, but the `Document Length` is 0 bytes.
curl the $URL works just fine and obtained 228 bytes.
So what's wrong with it?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be a ApacheBench bug that it doesn't accept lower cased content-length header.